# Como retirar seta de voltar da tela inicial (flutter)?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, app, widget

Gente estou com um problema no momento em que faço logout tipo, eu aperto no icone pra fazer logout ele sai do app, só que quando logo novamente ele apresenta uma seta de voltar na tela inicial. meu código esta assim:

```
  IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
          onPressed: (){
            userModel.signOut();
            Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>LoginScreen())
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui veja se resolve vosso problema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978216/flutter-remove-back-button-on-appbar#:~:text=9%20Answers&text=You%20can%20remove%20the%20back,back%20to%20the%20earlier%20route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar o método `push`, que *empilha* uma nova tela a sua lista de telas no aplicativo, experimente usar o [pushAndRemoveUntil](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html):

```
IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
          onPressed: (){
            userModel.signOut();
            navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>LoginScreen()),
                (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
            );
          },
        ),
```

Esse método irá remover da pilha (fazer o `pop`) de todas as telas até o segundo argumento retornar verdadeiro. Como coloquei uma função que sempre retorna falso, ela irá remover todas, para enfim trazer a próxima tela.

Caso você tenha certeza que na sua pilha só existia uma tela, você pode usar também como sugerido nos comentários a função `pushReplacement`. Como o nome implica, ela faz o `push` substituindo a posição da tela atual:

```
IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
          onPressed: (){
            userModel.signOut();
            navigator.pushReplacement(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>LoginScreen()));
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    );
```